# Buffer file names in a given directory

Tags: c#, file-io, bufferedreader

I'm trying to find a way to buffer FileNames from a given directory in C#. By this I mean:

Given directory

> C:/MyDir

Which contains files:

> File1_orig.txt
>
> File1_edited.txt
>
> File2_orig.txt
>
> File2_edited.txt
>
> ...
>
> Filen_orig.txt
>
> Filen_edited.txt

I want to store the filenames(not the whole filepath, just the filename, e.g. String[] filename = Filen_orig.txt) into temporary strings and run a simple comparison on them to see if they contain a target string.

I would like to pass the strings into:

```
while(STILL FILES IN DIRECTORY)
{
    string[] exFileName = {BUFFER FILENAME HERE}
    string[] words = exFileName.Split('_');
    string[] toCompare = "edited";
            bool result;
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
                bool result = toCompare.Equals(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                if (result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("success");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

To check to see if the file being examined is edited (*_edited.txt) or an original (*_original.txt), and, if the file is edited, further process the file.

Does anyone know how to automate a filepath read?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - do you want to buffer the filenames themselves?  Or the content of the files?  Either way it seems that all your asking here is "how do I store a list of strings?"  The answer to which is most likely: with `List<string>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to see if any files contain the _edited bit, you can use:

```
bool success = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir").Any(p => p.Contains("_edited"));
```

I'm making a bit of a guess this is what you want because your code isn't very clear (nor is your description)

Edit: to show all edited files:

```
            foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir").Where(p => p.Contains("_edited")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}: edited", file);
        }
```

Also, must be using "System.Linq"

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know if there is a ContainsIgnoreCase function? I can't seem to fine one. Should I just convert all strings toLower or toUpper?

Comment: I would personally use ToLower but there might be a quicker way... p.ToLower().Contains("_edited") in that case. IMO use whatever makes most sense to you reading it, the difference in speed is likely to be very low.

Answer (score 1):

How about [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx)?

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");

// Get only subdirectories that contain the letter "p."
FileInfo[] files= di.GetFiles("*.txt");

foreach (FileInfo fi in files) 
{
   string exFileName = fi.FileName;
  ...
}
```